# Raspberry pi Arduino Libraries folder

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-based, arduino-ide

I've got a raspberry pi and arduino connected over serial port.
Everything works, except the Arduino IDE does not have an 'import library' section for adding new libraries.

I can only import libraries that come with the IDE.
I want to add more libraries to Arduino IDE on the pi and wanted to know where the libraries folder could be found.

So far I haven't found it anywhere.

Anyone got any experience with it?

Another heads up, running raspbian wheezy.

Comment: documents (or the linux equivalent)/arduino/libraries?  Not sure if you've looked there already. Taken from the guide here: http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries

Comment: Thats the issue, I have not been able to find a documents equivalent on raspbian yet.
The 'add libraries' option doesn't exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can add your libraries in

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/
```

then just include them with the include statement

```
#include <myAwesomeLib.h>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: This is a protected folder and requires admin privileges to add files. I have to launch file explorer in sudo mode using `sudo pcmanfm` in terminal to be able to drag the library in.